# Edit link not visible in one question

Tags: bug, user-interface, reviewing

Edit link was not shown in [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/60844/minimum-number-of-transpositions), question. Resolved with Raphael's edit.

I was logged in and the edit option was available in other questions.

I use Safari on iPhone, screenshot was taken 2016-07-21 22:00:00 UTC. The issue was there for at least 20 minutes earlier.

[image: edit disappeared]

Comment: Again, I think reports/requests about the app belong on [meta.SE].

Comment: @Raphael this is not the app and it occurred at only one post here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess from the scenario and the approximate timestamp that this happened between 2016-07-21 18:07:57 and 2016-07-21 22:01:15 UTC. **Please mention this information explicitly, it's important!**

There was a [pending suggested edit](https://cs.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/4988) at this time. When a suggested edit is pending, no other edit can be made.

When you use the “full” website:

- If you have less than 2000 reputation, the “improve” link is grayed out and a tooltip explains why.
- If you have at least 2000 reputation, clicking on the “edit” link popus up a screen where you can review the suggested edit, and you have the option to reject or approve it immediately and make your own edit in the same go (“Improve”, “Reject and improve”).

It seems that the mobile website doesn't display the “edit” link at all. The Android app (I don't know about the iPhone app) has the same problem. Stack Exchange's policy is that it's acceptable to have some features missing on the mobile site and in mobile apps, and reviewing is one of these features. But it should still explain why editing is not possible (e.g. keep the “edit” link and pop up a message with an explanation and a link to the question on the website).

This bug has been marked [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) [on the main meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161023/pending-edits-remove-the-edit-link-altogether-on-mobile-site).